# How to stop Ansible from starting then restarting a service?

Tags: ansible

In many of my Ansible roles I have a handler to restart a service and a task to make sure the service is enabled and started. When this is a first run Ansible will start my service (Ensure mongodb is started and enabled) and then at the end run the restart handler. How do I tell Ansible to only start it once.

Sample play:

```
---
- name: Install MongoDB package
  yum: name="mongodb-org-{{ mongodb_version }}" state=present

- name: Configure mongodb
  template: src=mongod.conf.j2 dest=/etc/{{ mongodb_config_file }} owner=root group=root mode=0644
  notify: mongodb restart

- name: Ensure mongodb is started and enabled
  service: name={{ mongodb_daemon_name }} state=started enabled=yes
```

Comment: Handlers triggered through `notify` should only be triggered when the task reports as changed (Docs here: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_intro.html#handlers-running-operations-on-change). So that play should be fine as is. What output are you seeing on multiple runs?

Comment: As a separate thing, you shouldn't need that `changed_when` on the final task as that is going to throw the reporting of task changing for no good reason. The service module is pretty solid and makes a good job of explaining when something has been changed or not so I wouldn't override it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been a while since I asked this but anywho, if it helps, the solution I ended up with is below...

The trick is to...

1. Have the `service` task in the `tasks/main.yml` file with the parameters `state: started` and `enabled: yes` split out into their own tasks
2. For the `Ensure mongodb is started` task `register` a `mongodb_service_started` variable
3. Use the newly registered variable `mongodb_service_started` in the `when` clause of the `Restart mongodb` `handler` to only run when the `Ensure mongodb is started` task did **NOT** change

This ensures that your application does not get `started` then subsequently `restarted` in the same play and prevents your application from being stopped when it is running some critical function on startup. For example database migrations. Restarting a service right after it's been started can cause an inconsistent state.

**tasks/main.yml**

```
---
- name: Install MongoDB package
  yum: 
    name: "mongodb-org-{{ mongodb_version }}" 
    state: present
  notify: Restart mongodb

- name: Configure mongodb
  template: 
    src: mongod.conf.j2 
    dest: "/etc/{{ mongodb_config_file }}"
    owner: root 
    group: root 
    mode: 0644
  notify: Restart mongodb

- name: Ensure mongodb is started
  service: 
    name: "{{ mongodb_daemon_name }}" 
    state: started
  register: mongodb_service_started

- name: Ensure mongodb is enabled
  service: 
    name: "{{ mongodb_daemon_name }}"
    enabled: yes
```

**handlers/main.yml**

```
---
- name: Restart mongodb
  service: 
    name: "{{ mongodb_daemon_name }}" 
    state: started
  when: mongodb_service_started.changed == False
```

Answer (score 5):

Insert a `flush_handlers` task just in the front of the server started task to run the restart handler. Like:

```
- name: flush handlers
  meta: flush_handlers

## your service start task
- name:  Ensure mongodb is started and enabled
  service:
    service: name={{ mongodb_daemon_name }} state=started enabled=yes
```

If handlers are notified, the handler will restart the services (I assume you have handlers that restart the services).

If handlers are not notified, the Ensure service started task will start the service if it is not already started.

Comment: Very clean setup, thank you. Just for completeness, I split the task and put ´enabled=yes` in front of the flush_handlers, although it should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking something like this:

```
---
- name: Install MongoDB package
  yum: name="mongodb-org-{{ mongodb_version }}" state=present
  register: mongodb_install

- name: Configure mongodb
  template: src=mongod.conf.j2 dest=/etc/{{ mongodb_config_file }} owner=root group=root mode=0644
  notify: mongodb restart

- name: Ensure mongodb is started and enabled
  service: name={{ mongodb_daemon_name }} state=started enabled=yes
  when: mongodb_install.changed
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of <strike>two</strike> three ways.

#### Option #1.  Remove the state from the task that enables the service and move it to a handler.

According to the [Ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#handlers-running-operations-on-change), "notify handlers are always run in the same order they are defined."  Since `started` is [idempotent](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/service_module.html) and `restarted` always starts the service, the second handler (start) won't run if the first one does (restart).

```
# roles/mongodb/tasks/main.yml

- name: Install MongoDB package
  yum: name="mongodb-org-{{ mongodb_version }}" state=present

- name: Configure mongodb
  template: src=mongod.conf.j2 dest=/etc/{{ mongodb_config_file }} owner=root group=root mode=0644
  notify: mongodb restart

- name: Ensure mongodb is started and enabled
  service: name={{ mongodb_daemon_name }} enabled=yes
  notify: mongodb start
```

```
# roles/mongodb/handlers/main.yml

- name: mongodb restart
  service: name={{ mongodb_daemon_name }} state=restarted

- name: mongodb start
  service: name={{ mongodb_daemon_name }} state=started
```

**However**, handlers are only triggered if the task is changed, so this doesn't ensure that the service is running if neither of those tasks are considered changed.  For instance, if the service was already installed, enabled, and configured earlier, but someone has logged on to the host and shut it down manually, then it won't be started when this playbook is run.

#### Option #2.  Add a post_task that always runs and ensures the service has been started.

Handlers [are flushed](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#using-roles) before post tasks, so if the configuration has been changed, either during first installation or because it changed, the service will either be started or restarted.  However, if nothing has changed and the service isn't running for some reason, it will explicitly be started during the post_task.

```
# roles/mongodb/tasks/main.yml

- name: Install MongoDB package
  yum: name="mongodb-org-{{ mongodb_version }}" state=present

- name: Configure mongodb
  template: src=mongod.conf.j2 dest=/etc/{{ mongodb_config_file }} owner=root group=root mode=0644
  notify: mongodb restart

- name: Ensure mongodb is started and enabled
  service: name={{ mongodb_daemon_name }} enabled=yes
```

```
# In your playbook, e.g., site.yml

- hosts: all
  roles:
    - mongodb
  post_tasks:
    - name: Ensure mongodb is running
      service: name={{ mongodb_daemon_name }} state=started
```

#### Option #3.  Like Option #1, except always trigger the "start" handler

```
# roles/mongodb/tasks/main.yml

# ...same as Option #1 above...

- name: Ensure mongodb is started and enabled
  service: name={{ mongodb_daemon_name }} enabled=yes
  notify: mongodb start
  changed_when: yes
```

As long as seeing a "change" in your output doesn't bother you, this will work the way you want.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a handler (in the handlers directory of your role) then you do not need an additional task to start/enable mongo. In your handler you should not start but restart (`state=restarted`). When notified for the first time it will start and enable your service, and in future when the service is running, it will re-start.

```
- name: mongodb restart
  service: name={{ mongodb_daemon_name }} state=restarted enabled=yes
```

No additional task required.

Comment: The problem with this is in subsequent plays, the handler wont fire off if nothing changed and there will be no state to make sure the service is started. One thing i came up with is flushing the handlers just before this task, so that the service is already in the started state.